# How to debug a Flink application for memory and garbage collection?

Tags: debugging, memory-management, apache-flink

I'm using Flink 1.1.4 and have added to `flink-conf.yaml` the configuration parameters for memory debugging, as stated in [Memory and Performance Debugging](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/setup/config.html#memory-and-performance-debugging):

```
taskmanager.debug.memory.startLogThread: true
taskmanager.debug.memory.logIntervalMs: 1000
```

After restarting Flink, I'm seeing the new parameters added to the Job Manager interface, but I'm unable to see any new logs.

Any idea about what I may be missing?

Comment: Are you checking jobmanager logs or taskmanager logs? I believe if you see taskmanager logs you might get something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was resolved in this [mailinglist](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Using-memory-logging-in-Flink-td3970.html)

Key extracts, including one that confirmed the exact settings were tested succesfully:

> That is exactly the right way to do it. Logging has to be at least
> INFO and the parameter "taskmanager.debug.memory.startLogThread" set
> to true. The log output should be under
> "org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager".
>
> Do you see other outputs for that class in the log?
>
> Make sure you restarted the TaskManager processes after you changed
> the config file.

> Someone else just used the memory logging with the exact described
> settings - it worked.
>
> There is probably some mixup, you may be looking into the wrong log
> file, or may setting the a value in a different config...

> How do you start the flink cluster? If it's a standalone cluster and
> you don't use a shared directory, then you'll find the log of the
> taskmanager on the machine on which the taskmanager runs. If you use
> YARN then you can activate log aggregation to retrieve the log easily
> after the job has finished.